# "Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)" when querying cosmos data and using to_sql from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, azure, sqlalchemy, azure-cosmosdb

First I query my cosmos data and put it into a dataframe. Then I connect to my database and try using to_sql:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(r'Driver=SQL Server;Server={SERVERNAME},1433;Database=cosmosTest;Trusted_Connection=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=0;')
    conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
    engine = create_engine(conn_str,echo=True)
    conn = engine.connect()

    df.to_sql('Document', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)
```

When I try and run my script I run into this error message

> ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)')

I'm not sure if I'm receiving this error due to something I'm doing wrong or if the data I'm querying from cosmos doesn't play well with SQL Server. I've checked a couple other posts about this issue, but they didn't really pertain to me. Any suggestions on what I can try here?

Comment: if you run this without the `df.to_sql` and replace that with `print("Connection Complete")` does it actually print Connection Complete?

Comment: `Driver=SQL Server` is ancient. Can you try installing and using `Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` or `Driver=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server` instead?

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn Yes, it will successfully print that out.

Comment: @GordThompson Yeah, looks like I already have ODBC Driver 17 so I'll try that out.

Comment: @GordThompson I'm now receiving this error ```('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Table-valued parameter 22, to a parameterized string has no table type defined.``` using that driver.. hmm.

Comment: Does your DataFrame have one or more columns that do not contain scalar values (e.g., int, str) but instead contain something like a list, tuple, dict, series, etc.?

Comment: @GordThompson yes, I do actually have a column that is a list. I may not even need it. I'm going to try and delete the column from the dataframe and see if that works. Would you happen to know what to do if I did want to use that column though?

Comment: @GordThompson It worked btw, thanks so much for leading me in the right direction! If you have any suggestions, say if I wanted to use that column instead of dropping, I'd greatly appreciate that as well.

Comment: At the very least you could convert the list to a string using `json.dumps()` and then store the string in an [n]varchar(max) column. SQL Server has [JSON features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) that you can use with that data.